# Create multiple pie-charts with percentages by looping through columns using ggplot

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to loop through some variables (`col_names`) and then plot a `pie_chart` with `percentages` to each category. I could not find any code to re-use using this chart, but only bar charts or time series. [This one was the closest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66843749/dplyr-or-r-base-looping-through-specific-variables-to-produce-individual-pie-c).

This is a simulate code to reproduce

```
ds <- data.frame(
    cat_Var1 = rep(c("stay","go"), 20),
    cat_var2 = rep(c("male","female"), 20),
    cat_var3 = rep(c("dogs","cats","birds"), 40)
)

col_names <- ds %>% select(cat_Var1:cat_var3) %>% names()
for(i in col_names) {
  plot <- ds %>% 
    count(.data[[i]]) %>% 
    mutate(per = n/sum(n)) %>% 
    ggplot() +
    geom_bar(aes(x="", y=per, fill=factor(i)), stat="identity", width = 1)+
    coord_polar("y", start=0, direction = -1)
  print(plot)
}
```

I would like to use tidyverse functions (if possible). Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you first create a function that create a ggplot from one of your categorical columns, then you can use `purrr::map` to apply that function on each of the columns. The resulting list of ggplots can be assembled with e.g. `patchwork`. You could do it like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

theme_set(theme_void())

ds <- tibble(
  var1 = rep(c("stay","go"), 15),
  var2 = rep(c("male","female"), 15),
  var3 = rep(c("dogs","cats","birds"), 10)
)

pieplotter <- function(col) {
  tibble(var = col) %>% 
    count(var) %>% 
    mutate(
      p = n/sum(n),
      y_mid = lag(cumsum(p), default = 0) + (p/2) 
    ) %>% 
    ggplot() +
    geom_col(
      aes(x = "", y = p, fill = var)
    ) +
    coord_polar(theta = "y") +
    geom_text(
      aes(x = "", y = y_mid, label = scales::percent(p))
    ) +
    theme(
      axis.text.x = element_blank()
    )
}

map(ds, pieplotter) %>% patchwork::wrap_plots()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: fantastic! Is there any way to use specific columns from the ds instead of using all data frame?

Comment: yep, you can use  `ds %>% select(...) %>% map(pieplotter)`

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that `col_names` is a char vector which means the `i` in `fill=factor(i)` is a string when it really should be a symbol. In this case `ggplot` interprets the fill value as a vector with one value in it, so the pie chart is one solid color.

The call to `geom_bar` should actually be this:

```
geom_bar(aes(x="", y=per, fill=factor(!!sym(i))), stat="identity", width = 1)
```

Explanation:

- `sym` converts the string given with `i` to a symbol
- `!!` evaluates the symbol which references the column holding the categories for the pie chart in the dataframe being passed

Comment: Amazing and thanks for explaining each part of your code. The only thing that is still missing is the percentage within each segment in the pie chart.  If possible,  do you know how to plug this information into the graph? Thank you!